# setter method not being called in struts 2

Tags: java, liferay

I am doing struts2 + spring +hibernate + liferay integration. In that case the setter method is not being invoked inside struts2 Action class. The name of properties which I am sending through jsp is kept same both in Action class as well as form .Then too setter method is not executing. I need to insert the properties into database so I need those properties inside my Java class .Please tell me where I went wrong..Any help would be appreciated. The code for Action class is as follows:-

```
public class AddUserAction extends ActionSupport   implements ModelDriven<User> {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4587665276501838677L;

    private String name="";
    private String place=null;
    private String state=null;
    private User user = new User();
    private List<User> userList = new ArrayList<User>();

    private List<String> validateErrors;
    private UserDAO userDao;



    public AddUserAction(UserDAO userDao) {
        this.userDao = userDao;
    }
    @Override
    public User getModel() {
    return user;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }
    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
        System.out.println("hello");
    }
    @Override
    public String execute() throws Exception {
        //validateBookmark();

        userDao.saveUser(user);
        setUserList(userDao.listUser());
        System.out.println("List users"+userDao.listUser());
        return SUCCESS;
    }


    /*public void validateBookmark() throws Exception {
        Student studentObject = getNewStudent();
        validateErrors = new ArrayList<String>();
        StudentValidator validator = new StudentValidator();

        if(validator.validateStudent(studentObject, validateErrors)) {
            StudentLocalServiceUtil.addStudent(studentObject);
            addActionMessage(MessageStore.STUDENT_ADDED_SUCCESSFUL);

        }
        else {
            //handle the error massage 
        addActionError(MessageStore.BOOKMARK_ADDED_FAILED);
            addFieldError("failed", MessageStore.BOOKMARK_ADDED_FAILED);
            Iterator<String> errorIter = validateErrors.iterator();
            int count = 0;
            while (errorIter.hasNext()) {
                String error = errorIter.next();
                addFieldError("error" + count, error);
                count++;
            }
        }
    }*/

    /**
     * Create a new Bookmark Object from the view
     * @return 
     */
    /*private User getNewUSer() {
        User user =  new User();
        user.setName(getName());
        user.setPlace(getPlace());
        user.setState(getState());

        return user;
    }*/

    /*
     * Getters and Setters start here
     */
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        System.out.println("name is hfdj");
    }

    public List<String> getValidateErrors() {
        return validateErrors;
    }

    public void setValidateErrors(List<String> validateErrors) {
        this.validateErrors = validateErrors;
    }

    public String getPlace() {
        return place;
    }

    public void setPlace(String place) {
        this.place = place;
    }

    public String getState() {
        return state;
    }

    public void setState(String state) {
        this.state = state;
    }
    public void setUserList(List<User> userList) {
        this.userList = userDao.listUser();
    }
    public List<User> getUserList() {
        return userList;
    }

}
```

The code of JSP is as follows:-

```
<s:form action="adduserrecord">
      <s:textfield name="name" label="Student Name" value="abhi"/>
      <s:textfield name="place" label="Student Place" value=""/>
      <s:textfield name="state" label="Student State" value=""/>
      <s:submit value="Add User" align="center"/>
</s:form>
```

I want to clarify one thing that there is no problem in the hibernate section as the values inserted are null. But the problem is I want to actually store the values passed through the jsp. So help me please..thanx in advance.

User.java

```
@Entity(name = "user")
@Table(name="USER")
public class User {

    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String place;
    private String state;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="USER_ID")
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(name="USER_NAME")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Column(name="USER_PLACE")
    public String getPlace() {
        return place;
    }
    public void setPlace(String place) {
        this.place = place;
    }

    @Column(name="USER_STATE")
    public String getState() {
        return state;
    }
    public void setState(String state) {
        this.state = state;
    }

}
```

Comment: And what is in your `User.java` model?

Comment: @Parkash: I have added User.java in my question..

Comment: If your `User` model contains the same properties (`name, place and state`), then why are you duplicating them in your action class (`AddUserAction`)?

Comment: I tried with non-duplication also..i.e I removed the getters and setters from AddUserAction and run the code..then too null values are inserted into database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply, following changes in your view and action should work, as suggested in given reference:

**view:**

```
<s:form action="adduserrecord">
      <s:textfield name="user.name" label="Student Name" value="abhi" />
      <s:textfield name="user.place" label="Student Place" value="" />
      <s:textfield name="user.state" label="Student State" value="" />
      <s:submit value="Add User" align="center" />
</s:form>
```

**action:**

```
public class AddUserAction extends ActionSupport implements ModelDriven<User> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4587665276501838677L;

    private User user;

    @Override
    public String execute() throws Exception {
        // Here you will find your user object populated with form fields
        userDao.saveUser(user);
        return SUCCESS;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }
}
```

[**Reference**](http://www.codejava.net/frameworks/struts/handling-form-data-in-struts2)

Comment: `Struts2` will automatically fetch values of form’s fields into the mapped `JavaBean` object.

Comment: I think the answer is very close to the real solution..thats why I marked it as accepted..but however the problem still persists.

Comment: I also never worked with `Struts2`, but given an answer based on that reference.

Comment: Did you try removing the annotation in your `user` bean? Because, that is the only other difference.

Comment: i tried with annotation removal..and I got exception-org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: com.meera.domain.User